# Is it correct to say that "WE" feel only 5/140 of the actual weight of brain as buoyancy acts on brain due to cerebrospinal fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics, buoyancy, biology

Many sources of biological sciences (e.g.https://medium.com/@drvnx/what-is-that-thing-without-which-we-are-dead-f556fb1029ef )  say that the actual weight of brain is almost 1400gwt but as brain floats in a fluid known  as cerebrospinal fluid CSF due to which there acts an upward buoyant force on it and hence "WE" do not feel it's actual weight as 1400gwt."WE" feel it's weight only almost 50gwt.
Now as a physicist's view is this statement right or wrong? As having a stone and a bucket of water on a tray on our head will weight equally whether  the stone is separately on tray or inside the bucket of water.

Comment: Fuuny formulation of the title. A statement is correct or not, it does not matter who is making it, physicist or not.

Comment: I can't feel ANY weight of brain. Resist the obvious reply!

Comment: It would be best to give links to at least a few of those "many sources".

Comment: Why 5/140 instead of 1/28 ?

Comment: What on Earth is a gwt?

Comment: @N.Virgo, a gwt is a gram weight. That is, a force equal to the force of gravity on 1 gram near the Earth's surface. It is used instead of talking about a weight of 1 gram because weight is a force and the gram is a unit of mass, not of force.

Comment: @Peter I've never seen gwt used in a physics context. Seeing as we're rounding significantly here we could just write 140N & 5N respectively instead?

Comment: Try this: Take a (sensitive) kitchen scale, put a bowl with some water in onto the scale. Now calibrate the scale (e.g. put it to 0g), and then put something in the water that will swim (a fruit, some flour etc...). What do you think? Will the scale still show 0?

Comment: I don't think fruit swim.

Comment: I literally don't want to think about how much my brain feels it weighs, there must be a pun in there somewhere, but I really believe that!

Comment: Is there some reason you avoided letting Stack Exchange format the URL as a clickable link, by not leaving any space between it and the "e.g."?  I would edit myself but 1-character edits are too small for people without 2k rep on this site.

Answer (score 54):

Try not to be too pedantic with the biologists. They have our medical health to worry about.

What is most likely that they are really trying to convey but failed to precisely state, is that if the brain is put on a table, the 1400gwt  would have crushed the tissues in the brain itself. That it is not crushed is because this weight is distributedly propped up by the CSF so that each little piece of the brain is experiencing upthrust. In this way, the force propping the brain up at the bone-brain interface only needs to be 50gwt, and thus the brain would not be crushed by its own weight.

Comment: I'd like offer the following as a support/supplement for this answer. Consider the such an experiment, lie down with unsupported head and you will feel brain's weight. The brain might not "feel itself" suspended in the fluid, to give this a more direct analogy it's like weighting yourself in water. Your legs need way less strength to support yourself in a full body bath than on dry ground, but something needs to support the bath and you... that would be the neck for brain.

Comment: I like that this answer also answers where the confusion came from and correctly conveys what the authors were actually trying to tell.

Comment: Thanks. I have taught professionally, so I am very used to deciphering what is the intent behind students' (and teachers') statements.

Comment: And as long as you're not moving, there's no difference between being in water and being encased in a solid in the same position as the water that holds you up. Your weight is still on your skin in water, its just spread over all the downward-facing skin on your body instead of just your feet.

Comment: @bdsl And if anyone's wondering why your brain isn't encased in a solid, it's because that would mean any swelling of the brain would be much worse much more quickly

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms: Do you have a source for that claim? The sources I find online \[[1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK519007/), [2](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms/def/cerebrospinal-fluid)\] state that cerebrospinal fluid serves to nourish the brain, remove waste, and cushion the brain from injury; I think that all of those roles are better served by a fluid than by a solid casing, so I don't think we need to invoke brain swelling to account for it.

Comment: Please don't blame the biologists, especially for a blog article asking you to "understand this amazing creativity of God".

Answer (score 17):

This type of question arises regularly on this site. the brain might be floating more or less weightlessly within the CSF but the skull case that contains the CSF does experience the weight of the brain; it is transferred to the skull case by the CSF.

Comment: And the CSF and skull add additional weight to be supported.  Personally, my brain 'feels' weightless.  Maybe that's my problem.